# HTML5 <input> type = number prevent user from violating the min="" or max="" value

Tags: php, html

First of all you can just enter a different number by hand and then you can just go over or under the specific values. Also you could inspect the element and set a different min or max yourself. How would I validate this? Or should I just set a check on the SQL for the values to either be 0 or 1.

This is my code right now:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="-koowa-form">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input  type="text" name="naam" id="naam" size="40" maxlength="255" value="<?= $test->naam; ?>" placeholder="<?= translate( 'naam' ); ?>" />
            <input  type="text" name="kleur" id="kleur" size="40" maxlength="255" value="<?= $test->kleur; ?>" placeholder="<?= translate( 'kleur' ); ?>" />
            <input  type="number" name="active" id="active" size="40" min="0" max="1" value="<?= $test->active; ?>" placeholder="<?= translate( 'active' ); ?>" />
        </div>
        <input type="color" name="kleurcode" value="<?= $test->kleurcode; ?>"  
    </div>
</form>
```

What I have right now just seems to be incredibly messy and I see threads from over 3 years ago about this issue. Wondering if there's a easy and clean fix for this or I should just do it differently.

EDIT: To clarify I'm aware it will obviously have to be checked in the back-end, but I want to make it work properly in the front-end too. This just seems incredibly sloppy and unprofessional.

FIX: For now I've done this, adding a validation error message with jquery sometime later

EDIT: Fix was horrible added a reuseable javascript only fix now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkMinMax(event) {
    var value = this.value,
        min = this.getAttribute('min'),
        max = this.getAttribute('max');

    if(value < min)
        this.value = min;
    else if(value > max)
        this.value = max;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('active').addEventListener('keyup', checkMinMax);
});
```

Comment: Well, the safest thing would be to validate it server side, Check that the values is within the accepted parameters, if they are then proceed, if not, throw error.

Comment: Well obviously but it's incredibly messy that it can be so easily violated in the front-end. Just seems clunky to throw an error to the user for something they can just fill in. Do you have any idea how to get it working properly on the frontend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only safely inspect these things on server side. At the client side, everything is controlled by the client. The HTML code can be altered at the client side, and the javascript code can be altered at the client side.
So *nothing* that your server receives from a client can be guaranteed! This is the first lesson in web security. Checking of valid input has to be done at server side using a server side language like `PHP`.

The frontend can only make it "easy" for the user to enter valid data. For this there are a lot of things invented like `min,max,type="number", required` etc. But it depends on the browser how well these things are actually implemented and supported. So yes, from a frontend cross browser perspective we have a long way to go to make it look less messy.

To make it work in "all" browsers (I never include IE in "all"), you can use various javascript checks on your inputs to make sure the `min` and `max` are not being violated.
One nice way to do that would be to put an `oninput` listener on the inputs, using `oninput="validate()"` inside the html. Then use a function like `valBetween` (see below) to set the new value.

```
function validate() {
    this.value = valBetween(this.value, this.min, this.max);
}

function valBetween(v, min, max) {
    return (Math.min(max, Math.max(min, v)));
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've learned that lesson a while ago when someone could upload some files with a different extension as a photo and it completely screwed over the site throwing errors everywhere. But I just want to make it tidy on the user end, it's silly you can just fill it in by hand and then violate the min/max value...

Comment: @StrahBehry I agree, but unfortunately most of these things depend on support from the browser. You can add Javascript checks to make sure they do not violate the min-max rules you set.

Comment: @StrahBehry a very simple js solution (but it can be done more elegant) is this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/Validateaninputfieldwithminimumandmaximumvalues.htm

Comment: @StrahBehry updated my answer to provide a better way of checking with javascript. (I did not test it though, so let me know if it did not work)

Comment: Fixed it using onkeyup, basically does the same as what you posted, thanks a lot.

Comment: Nvm that was horrible, put a actually good one now that doesn't need anything in the html input form itself.